# Git can't display russian

Tags: git, unicode

I use Git Bash on Windows. When I type for example `git status`,  I have:

```
        modified:   programming/_methods and theory/programming.tex
        modified:   "\320\274\320\260\321\202\320\265\320\274\320\260\321\202\320\270\320\272\320\260/
\321\202\320\265\320\276\321\200\320\270\321\217\320\262\320\265\321\200\320\276\321\217\321\202\320
\275\320\276\321\201\321\202\320\270 \320\270321\201\321\202\320\260\321\202\320\270\321\201\321\202\320\270\320\272
\320\260/\321\215\320\273\320\265\320\274\320\265\320\275\321\202\321\213 \321\202\320\265\320\276\321\200\320\270\320\270 
\320\262\320\265\321\200\320\276\321\217\321\202\320\275\320\276\321\201\321\202\320\270.pdf"
```

This is because of Russian symbols in folders.

I don't know git's settings, can anyone help me, how to make git display name of the folder in Russian?

Comment: Would it be a problem with git? Or perhaps a problem with the terminal not parsing encoding properly? Do you have a plain text file with russian content laying around there? So that you can run `cat the-file` and see if the content is displayed correctly?

Comment: Try using `cmd` instead of `git bash`, does that make a difference?

Comment: Try `git -c core.quotepath=false status`. If it works, run `git config --global core.quotepath false`.

Comment: Which locale do you have in git-bash?

Comment: Other people, who wrote comments, thanks for your attention, but the answer by  @ElpieKay worked great, so the problem is solved. :) Good luck to you!